# Non-toric ring which is Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain, graded-rings, cohen-macaulay

I know a lot of examples of classes of *binomial* ideals $I$ in $S=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ whose $S/I$ is a Cohen-Macaulay domain. Basically, if $I$ is a toric ideal and there exists a monomial order $<$ on $S$ such that the initial ideal of $I$ with respect to $<$ is squarefree then $S/I$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

So far, I have never met a class of non-toric ideals $I$ such that $S/I$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring. Do you know some examples? Are they quite uncommon?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: I’m not too comfortable with this notion, but isn’t $K[x,y]/(xy)$ Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: Ah yes, you are right!

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: I can’t help with the new question, I don’t know what a toric ideal is…

Comment: Any local complete intersection is Cohen-Macaulay. In particular, any smooth variety and thus plentiful.

Comment: May you provide an esplicit example please?